Excel cell external unlinking is taking too much time for context sync
Working with custom excel formulas. When I try to unlink formula in the cells and put only the value back to the cells it takes too much time for context sync. How do I reduce the timing? Maybe it's because of the context sync in the loop, but not working without context sync. The toast message after the successful unlinking of the formulas comes very late almost takes 5 to 10 mins to show.
    async unlinkWorkbook() {
        try {
          Excel.run((ctx) => {
            var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets;
            worksheets.load('name');
            var usedRange: Excel.Range[] = [];
            var cellProperties: any = [];
            return ctx
              .sync()
              .then(function () {
                usedRange = [];
                cellProperties = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                  usedRange[i] = worksheets.items[i].getUsedRange();
                  usedRange[i].load(['address', 'values', 'formulas', 'text']);
                  const propertiesToGet = usedRange[i].getCellProperties({
                    address: true,
                  });
                  cellProperties.push(propertiesToGet);
                }
              })
              .then(ctx.sync)
              .then(async () => {
                var count = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                  await ctx.sync().then(async () => {
                    var cells: any = [];
                    // To load the spill values of each cell in the range
                    usedRange[i].formulas.forEach((array, xindex) => {
                      array.forEach((formula, yindex) => {
                        var location = cellProperties[i].value[xindex][yindex].address.split('!')[1];
                        var cell = worksheets.items[i].getRange(location);
                        // Load the spill values of the cell
                        cells.push(cell.getSpillingToRangeOrNullObject().load(['values']));
                      });
                    });
    
                    await ctx.sync().then(() => {
                      var k = 0;
                      usedRange[i].formulas.forEach((array, xindex) => {
                        array.forEach((formula, yindex) => {
                          if (
                            formula &&
                            isNaN(formula) &&
                            (formula.toLowerCase().indexOf('q.get') !== -1 ||
                              formula.toLowerCase().indexOf('q.getlist') !== -1)
                          ) {
                            var location = cellProperties[i].value[xindex][yindex].address;
                            var cell = worksheets.items[i].getRange(location);
                            // Check if cells contains the spill values or not
                            if (cells[k].values) {
                              cell = cell.getResizedRange(cells[k].values.length - 1, cells[k].values[0].length - 1);
                              cell.formulas = cells[k].values; // replace cells with spill values
                            } else {
                              const value = usedRange[i].values[xindex][yindex];
                              cell.values = [[value]]; // replace cells with normal values
                              if (!isNaN(value) && value.toString().indexOf('.') != -1) {
                                cell.numberFormat = [['0.00']];
                              }
                            }
                            count++;
                          }
                          k++;
                        });
                      });
                    });
                  });
                }
    
                if (count > 0) {
                  await ctx.sync();
                  this.apiDataService.showUnlinkModalFn({
                    severity: 'success',
                    summary: 'Success',
                    detail: 'Formulas successfully unlinked.',
                  });
                } else {
                  this.apiDataService.showBannerUp({
                    severity: 'info',
                    summary: 'Unlink',
                    detail: 'No formulas found in the selected range to unlink!',
                  });
                }
              });
          });
        } catch {
          this.apiDataService.showUnlinkModalFn({
            severity: 'error',
            summary: 'Failed To Unlink Formulas',
            detail: `Something went wrong.
          Please try again!`,
            type: 'workbook',
          });
        }
      }


Restructure so that there is no ctx.sync in any loops. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern

But then I am not getting spill cells values to replace

Then create a new Stack Overflow issue with the new problem. Just don't continue with code that has a sync inside a loop.

can you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78964603/excel-cell-external-unlinking-is-taking-too-much-time-for-context-sync-for-singl
