Excel cell external unlinking is taking too much time for context sync for single worksheet
Working with custom excel formulas. When I try to unlink formula in the cells and put only the value back to the cells it takes too much time for context sync. How do I reduce the timing? but not working without context sync. The toast message after the successful unlinking of the formulas comes very late almost takes 5 to 10 mins to show.
Previously it was in happening because context.sync was in loop while I was iterating over workbook currently I am only doing it for single sheet but it is still taking too much time.
async unlinkSelectedOrWorksheet(unlinkLevel: string) {
    try {
      Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
        let range: Excel.Range;
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        if (unlinkLevel == 'worksheet') {
          range = await sheet.getUsedRange(true);
        } else {
          range = await ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        }
        range.load(['values', 'formulas', 'address', 'text']);
        const propertiesToGet = range.getCellProperties({
          address: true,
        });

        return ctx.sync().then(() => this.processWorksheetOrCellsFormula(range, sheet, propertiesToGet, ctx));
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.apiDataService.showUnlinkModalFn({
        severity: 'error',
        summary: 'Failed To Unlink Formulas',
        detail: `Something went wrong.
      Please try again!`,
        type: unlinkLevel,
      });
    }
  }

  async processWorksheetOrCellsFormula(range: any, sheet: any, propertiesToGet: any, ctx: any) {
    const qcount = await this.unlinkQGetFormulasForSheet(range, sheet, propertiesToGet);
    const qgetlistcount = await this.unlinkQGetListFormulasForSheet(range, sheet, propertiesToGet, ctx);
    const count = qcount + qgetlistcount;

    if (count > 0) {
      await ctx.sync();

      this.apiDataService.showUnlinkModalFn({
        severity: 'success',
        summary: 'Success',
        detail: 'Formulas successfully unlinked.',
      });
    } else {
      this.apiDataService.showBannerUp({
        severity: 'info',
        summary: 'Unlink',
        detail: 'No formulas found in the selected range to unlink!',
      });
    }
  }

  async unlinkQGetFormulasForSheet(usedRange: any, worksheets: any, cellProperties: any) {
    let count = 0;

    usedRange.formulas.forEach((array: any, xindex: number) => {
      array.forEach((formula: any, yindex: any) => {
        if (
          formula &&
          isNaN(formula) &&
          formula?.toLowerCase().indexOf('q.get') !== -1 &&
          formula?.toLowerCase().indexOf('q.getlist') === -1
        ) {
          const location = cellProperties.value[xindex][yindex].address;
          const cell = worksheets.getRange(location);
          const value = usedRange.values[xindex][yindex];
          cell.values = [[value]]; // Replace with value
          if (!isNaN(value) && value.toString().indexOf('.') !== -1) {
            cell.numberFormat = [['0.00']];
          }
          count++;
        }
      });
    });

    return count;
  }

async unlinkQGetListFormulasForSheet(usedRange: any, worksheets: any, cellProperties: any, ctx: any) {
    let count = 0;
    const cells: any = [];

    usedRange.formulas.forEach((array: any, xindex: number) => {
      array.forEach((formula: any, yindex: number) => {
        const location = cellProperties.value[xindex][yindex].address.split('!')[1];
        const cell = worksheets.getRange(location);
        cells.push(cell.getSpillingToRangeOrNullObject().load(['values']));
      });
    });
    await ctx.sync();

    let k = 0;
    usedRange.formulas.forEach((array: any, xindex: any) => {
      array.forEach((formula: any, yindex: any) => {
        if (formula && isNaN(formula) && formula.toLowerCase().indexOf('q.getlist') !== -1) {
          const location = cellProperties.value[xindex][yindex].address;
          let cell = worksheets.getRange(location);

          if (cells[k].values) {
            cell = cell.getResizedRange(cells[k].values.length - 1, cells[k].values[0].length - 1);
            cell.formulas = cells[k].values; // Replace cells with spill values
          } else {
            const value = usedRange.values[xindex][yindex];
            cell.values = [[value]]; // Replace cells with normal values
            if (!isNaN(value) && value.toString().indexOf('.') !== -1) {
              cell.numberFormat = [['0.00']];
            }
          }
          count++;
        }
        k++;
      });
    });

    return count;
  }


Does this even work? I would expect unlinkQGetFormulasForSheet to need a context.sync, otherwise the count returned will be zero?

You are mixing together 2 different Promise-handling syntaxes: return ctx.sync().then(...) and await ctx.sync. This makes it hard to reason about whether there is a synchronicity error in your code.

Do you really need to pass ctx as a parameter? Isn't it global to the Excel.run?

Try putting a async ctx.sync() just before the return count.

You aren't using getSpillingToRangeOrNullObject properly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model#ornullobject-methods-and-properties
